# Group together by date, but show all rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Normally when I group stuff together it is for the obvious use to group together duplicates, but I am making a winners page that shows winners for a bunch of jackpots, some jackpots have 1 winner while other have 3, using `GROUP BY date` will work if there is only 1 winner but will only show 1 winner when there should be 3.

Here is my code

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM r_winners GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC");
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
print"<table class='cashout' style='width:100%;'>
<th colspan='3'>".$rows['jackpot_name']." Winners</th>
<tr>
<td style='width:33%;'>".$rows['winner']."</td><td style='width:33%;'>$".$rows['amount']."</td><td style='width:33%;'>".date("m/d/Y", $rows['date'])."</td></tr>
</tr></table>";
}
```

It prints out a table like such

```
---------------------------------------
Daily     Jackpot     Winners
Username|  $5.00   |  12/5/2012         // This table is right, because there is only 1 winner
---------------------------------------
```

Because there is only 1 winner then `GROUP BY` really has no affect here

Here is a table for multiple winners

```
---------------------------------------
Monthly     Jackpot     Winners
Username  |  $5.00   |  12/5/2012         // This table is wrong, because there should be 3 winners
---------------------------------------
```

It needs to look like this

```
---------------------------------------
Monthly     Jackpot     Winners
Username  |  $5.00   |  12/5/2012 
Username2 |  $2.00   |  12/5/2012
Username3 |  $1.00   |  12/5/2012        
---------------------------------------
```

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: This can maybe explain this better https://gist.github.com/4221167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to just use `ORDER BY` and reformat your loop, placing the table elements outside, and only printing the header once

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM r_winners ORDER BY date DESC");
print"<table class='cashout' style='width:100%;'>";
$jackpot_name = '';
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    if ($jackpot_name != $rows['jackpot_name']) {
        $jackpot_name = $rows['jackpot_name'];
        print "<th colspan='3'>".$rows['jackpot_name']." Winners</th>";
    }
    print "<tr><td style='width:33%;'>".$rows['winner']."</td><td style='width:33%;'>$".$rows['amount']."</td><td style='width:33%;'>".date("m/d/Y", $rows['date'])."</td></tr>";
}
print "</table>";
```

Comment: unfortunately all this does is put all of the rows under one table heading :/

Comment: @kira423: hadn't seen the example you linked, the above edit should work

Comment: had to make an edit to how my `jackpot_names` are made and add a unique variable, but works perfect thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use `GROUP BY` at all.  You are already using `ORDER BY` which will put your dates into logical "groupings".

In response to your comments about ho to output the results in one table, here is how you would need to modify your code.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM r_winners ORDER BY date DESC");
print "<table class='cashout' style='width:100%;'>";
print "<th colspan='3'>".$rows['jackpot_name']." Winners</th>";
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    print "<tr><td style='width:33%;'>".$rows['winner']."</td><td style='width:33%;'>$".$rows['amount']."</td><td style='width:33%;'>".date("m/d/Y", $rows['date'])."</td></tr>";
}
print "</table>";
```

Comment: this makes 3 tables for Monthly Jackpot winner, I need them all in 1 table

Comment: @kira423 Well of course you would need to change your HTML.  I thought your question was more around how to formulate the query.  If you are looking for a single HTML table any time you output a result set with various rows, the `<table>` open and close tags should exist outside your loop that outputs the records (table rows).

Comment: it is how to formulate it to do this https://gist.github.com/4221167 I am not sure how changing the html is going to do this

Comment: @kira423 See my updated answer for how you would need to modify your table output.

Comment: I'm not wanting everything in one big table, I'm still wanting a separate tables for each different set of winners and jackpot, so for each different date I need a new table but when the dates are the same I need all of the winners names in 1 table

Comment: You can certainly work out the display issues however you want.  You would just need to loop through the entire result set and create a new table each time you encountered a new date in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `GROUP BY` and only using `ORDER BY`.

Comment: this makes 3 tables for Monthly Jackpot winner, I need them all in 1 table

Comment: It'll only return 1 result set. You'll print 3 tables because you have your `print "<table..." code on the inside of the while. Create the table once and then iterate through the entire result set before closing the table.

Comment: even if the `<table>` and `</table>` are outside of the `while` loop its still going to create 3 separate `<th>` which is still going to mess it up when I want all 3 under 1 `table heading <th>`

Answer (score 0):

You should `GROUP BY Monthly ORDER BY Winners`, of course, if `Monthly` is unique, then you even don't need to `GROUP BY` it.

***Edit:***
After checking your php code, I think you need below:

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(winner_name) AS winner_names,
  SUM(the_value_column_you_want_to_sum) AS amount
FROM r_winners 
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because they are all on the same page, and it would only show one table when it should show multiple

Comment: Im not sure about the new code, when it comes to `SUM(the_value_column_you_want_to_sum) AS amount` I am not wanting to sum anything up, What I am trying to do is if there are more than 1 winner I want to list them all under the same table heading instead of 1 under 3 separate table headings